# can someone please explain REQ in express plz

Tags: javascript, express

I dont get how we use `req` in `express`. I undrstand that the server can respond back to client,but when it comes to `req` object im confused. Is `req` when the server is asking for somethong from the client?

Comment: Why don't you search in internet before posting here. https://alligator.io/nodejs/req-object-in-expressjs/

Comment: i did,i read the docs and been watching tutorials.just having hard time to understand.sorry i should have mentioned it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP is an application, client-server protocol. Everytime that a client want the server to perform an action, it has to make a request. The HTTP protocol defines a set of actions or verbs that are available to the client so it can make each request using one specific verb (GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, etc). It doesn't matter what verb the client uses, only the client can initiate a comunication with the server using one of that verbs. So this is how exactly an HTTP GET request looks like:

```
 GET / HTTP/1.1
 Host: example.com
 User-Agent: curl/7.69.1
 Accept: */*
```

The first line contains the verb used, in this case `GET`, the path requested, in this case `/`, and the protocol version, in this case `HTTP/1.1`. The next lines, are a set of key value pairs called the `headers` of that request, which can define a lot of aspects of the request made by the client to the server. By the way, an HTTP server never could or will start a request to a client, a client always is the one that make the request, and the server is always the one that response that request. One of the aspects of that request for example, is the destination host, that is present in the header `host` with the value of `example.com`. Bellow of the headers, all the HTTP requests have a blank line and then the body of the request, which normally contains the data that is sent from the client to the server. In this case, no data body is sent on the request.

Express is an HTTP server based on the HTTP module available on Node.js. Express simplifies the way that the native Node.js HTTP server works. Here is tipically how an Express app looks like:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();


// This is called a router
app.get('/path', (req, res) => {
    // This router will perform some action with the req object
    // And will send a response to the client 
});
```

So, on the example above, the method `app.get(...)`, available on Express applications, allows the server to deal with the GET requests that come from the client. The `app.get()` method takes two arguments, a `path` and a callback function. The `path` argument represent the string that goes after the name server, for example, in the URL `www.example.com/test`, the hostname is `www.example.com`, and the path is `/test`. That method `app.get()` is also called a `Router`. So, the router of the example will deal with the  `GET` requests to that server which also define `/path` value as the path the request is sent to. Once a request to the server fit those two conditions, that callback will be triggered.

So, finally we get to the answer. The `res` variable is an object (a set of key-pair values separated by commas and locked into curly braces), that contains the data of the HTTP request, into a friendly legible object. For example, if you want to print to the console the path that the client used, you can print it like this `console.log(req.path)`, or you can get all the headers of that HTTP request, you can use `console.log(req.headers)`. The `req` object is one of the 5 main objects in Express, in fact the Express documentation defines a ton of methods that you can use with the request object (`req`). To get deep into the request object, you can see the official Express documentation in this [link](https://expressjs.com/es/api.html#req). The callback defined into the router, can use the `req` object, to extract information of the client's request, process it and return a response to the client later.

Answer (score 0):

With an express server, you get two objects passed to a request handler.

`req` is data about the incoming request (things that were sent from the client).  It contains the headers on the request, it contains a parsed query string, it contains the URL path, it's generally the object where middleware puts things for request handlers to use.  While Express adds a bit more to this object, you can see the general concept of the `req` object by looking and the `http.IncomingMessage` object documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage).  This is what the object starts out as and then Express adds more to it.  The express version of the object is documented [here](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req).

`res` is the response object.  This is all about sending a response.  It will hold the outbound headers you want to send with the request.  It contains the methods you use for sending a response.  The core object is an `http.ServerResponse` object documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage) and then Express adds some more things to the object on top of that which is document [here](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res).

Comment: thank you so much,i get it now,the part thats confusing is when we res the req to the client back.

Comment: @AndrewBurkett - You should never be doing `res.send(req)` so I'm not sure what you mean in your last comment?  You should be using `req` to see what the request was that was sent from the client to your server and then create a response and use `res` to send that response back to the client.  `req` = incoming data, `res` = outgoing data.

Comment: app.get('/user/:id', function (req, res) {
  res.send('user ' + req.params.id
})                   the part thats confusing is if we got data from client, why are we sending same thing back? in the request.params.id , i hope im making sense

Comment: @AndrewBurkett - Odd.  You're just coming back here a month and a half later and asking more questions after you've already accepted an answer?  `res.send('user ' + req.params.id }` looks like some test or demo code to me as I can't imagine there would be any real world use to a route that only does this and nothing else.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just took a break from programming. Thank you for your help. So you saying the req.params.id you would not send back? Because you just sending back same thing.

Comment: @AndrewBurkett - That code would work just fine.  I just don't see the point of it.