# How do I extract data from my static js file and put the information into express and then send that to a database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I've already built a website that I want to extract data from a form. I have the logic set up but need the information to go to a database when the form is submitted. How do I extract the variables and put them into my express application and then send that info to mongoDB, the database I am using. Also, when the form is submitted, what should the action be for the form in html. Shouldn't it be index.html because I don't want the user to leave the site. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Here's my code:

HTML

<

```
div class="contactform">
                <form action="/" method="POST" class="form">
                    <input type="text" name='name' id='name' placeholder="Name">
                    <input type="email" name='email' id='email' placeholder="Email">
                    <textarea class="messages" placeholder="Messages...."></textarea>
                    <button class="submit">Send</button>
                </form>
<div>

Main.JS 
const alertMessage = document.querySelector('.alert');
function collectInfo () {
    if (name.value === '' || email.value === '') {
        alertMessage.innerHTML = 'Name And Email Required';

    } else {
        alertMessage.innerHTML = 'Success! Someone will be in touch with your soon!'

    }
}

const submit = document.querySelector('.submit');
submit.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
    const name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    collectInfo();
});

JS where express is deployed
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Form = require('./models/form.js');
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
const app = express();


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:/airplane_port', { useNewUrlParser: true,
useUnifiedTopology: true
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error('MongoDB connection error: ' + err);
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');



// Index Route
app.get('/index.html', function(req, res){
    console.log(Form.name);
});

app.post("/index.html", (req, res) => {

  });
```

const port = process.env.PORT || 5500;
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`http://localhost:${port}: server started`);
    })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default method of a form submit action is POST, so you need a POST route:

```
app.post( (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.send("ok");
})
```

I recommend you to set also the JSON middleware:

```
app.use(express.json());
```

Then, the values of your form's inputs, will be received so:

```
req.body === {inputOne: 'valueOne', inputTwo: 'valueTwo')
```

You only need to set the `name` attributes of the form's inputs, with the key that you want to receive it:

```
<input type="text" name='inputOne' ...>
```

Comment: Munoz. Hi, this code help me quite a bit. I only used the console.log(req.body) and it worked. The information showed up in the terminal. The question I have is why did you think to use req.body?

Comment: Maybe this could help to understand, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62097540/can-someone-please-explain-req-in-express-plz/62098345#62098345

Comment: Munoz. Thank you so much, it does help a little. Just one more question. Does the req.body know that the information is sent from the form is a request because it is in form tag or because of the use of action and method.

Comment: Exclusivelly because the use of the action and the method.

Comment: Hi @Alanaj if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

first delete this lines

```
const submit = document.querySelector('.submit');
submit.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
    const name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    collectInfo();
});
```

and in your form submit your form like this

```
 <form action="/index" method="POST" class="form">
 <input type="text" name='name' id='name' placeholder="Name">
 <input type="email" name='email' id='email' placeholder="Email">
 <textarea class="messages" name="message" placeholder="Messages...."></textarea>
 <input type="submit">Send</button>
 </form>
```

and then handle your submited form like this

```
app.post("/index.html", (req, res) => {
    const {name,email,message}= req.body
     console.log(req.body)
  });
```

Comment: the name, email, message lines has an error to do with the equal sign

Comment: also you won't be able to retrieve the message you have to add it as a name attribute  `name="message"`

Comment: {name,email,message}= req.body, but I think I found a part of my answer with the response from above. I consoled.log (req.body) to the server and it returned my form information.

Comment: hig Thank you so much!  The output i wanted work but I don't get how. Don't I have to define those variable somewhere and also that's why I don't understand why you deleted the code to do that. How did you req.body would work?